# Как скомпилировать программу на Python в которой используется pyautogui и keyboard

Tags: python, python-3.x

Проблема заключается в том что возникает ошибка при открытии скомпилированого exe в котором используется pyautogui и keyboard.
Думаю это не сильно важно но код, я решил прикрепить:

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
what = input("напиши(q):")


if what == "q":
    sleep(2)
    keyboard.press_and_release('alt+tab')
    print(pyautogui.position())

input()
```

Comment: В гугле пишут, что py2exe и pyinstaller могут сами интегрировать модули, собирая exe из файла.

Comment: Всё я разобрался с этим

Comment: Вы можете оставить свой ответ под своим вопросом для помощи другим людям, столкнувшимся с вашей проблемой